# Partitioned tables: How significant is the cost of moving rows between partitions by updating the partition key?

Tags: sql-server

**Using SQL Server 2014 Partitioned Tables;**

According to the below post:

[Can I move rows between partitions by updating the partition key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4511/can-i-move-rows-between-partitions-by-updating-the-partition-key)

I understand that we can move rows between partitions by changing the partition key.

What is the performance cost of moving rows between partitions by updating the partition key? Is it equivalent to having two tables, deleting a row from the 1st table and insert it into the second table? OR is it more efficient within partitions?

A link to an online article would be very helpful. I can't find the right Google search key for this question. Hopefully this post will help others.

Comment: If this is a follow up to a question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/, why not ask it there?

Answer (score 1):

It would be the former.

If you update any other column than the partition key, then the record stays in the same bucket, the column value gets changed and the transaction log gets a delete/insert (=update) to track the changes.

If you update the partition key, then that record no longer maps to that partition.  So it will delete the old record and insert the new record (into a new partition per the partitioning rules).  Note that the transaction log entry for this change requires writing the whole record as it is truly deleted in one partition then rewritten wholly into another, and not just a one column change.